# Estou com problema em criar meu botão de avançar, eu não estou conseguindo identificar

Tags: javascript

Olá! Eu sou novo em js, Eu estou com problema em criar meu botão de avançar, eu não estou conseguindo identificar

```
const btnAvancar = document.querySelector("btn-avancar");
let cartaoAtual = 0;

/*
são 3 cartões que estão em uma ul 
O objetivo é o botão de avançar de cartão em cartão*/ 


btnAvancar.addEventListener("click",function(){
                const cartoes = document.querySelectorAll(".cartao");

                cartaoAtual++;
                console.log(cartaoAtual)
                cartoes[cartaoAtual].classList.add('selecionado');
                
            });
```

Comment: Ola @DiegoRosa, Bem vindo ao [pt.so], vale apena você [edit] sua pergunta e criar um [mcve], dessa forma a comunidade vai entender melhor seu problema... mas posso indicar que esse selector esta estranho `...rySelector("btn-avancar")`, ele não informa se é uma classe `.` ou id `#`, então esta tratando como tag, vale verificar se é esse mesmo o objetivo.

Comment: O nome dado ao botão é de uma classe ou id.. esse select espera passa nome de classe ou id... classe será    ponto nome da classe e id hastag nome do id dessa maneira classe  ".btn-avancar"... id "#btn-avancar"

Comment: funcionou certinho, Muito Obrigado!!